# Embedded Spotify "follow button" is working intermittently

Tags: html, embed, spotify

Spotify's follow button is not working all the time, in this URL you can see a live preview of the button from the official documentation which is not working right now:

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/widgets/generate/follow-button/

During the last days I've seen that's not properly rendered in Chrome:

[Screenshot of the Spotify follow button error in the official documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgKHA.png)

I tried in Firefox, incognito and in mobile browsers with no luck.
Any idea if this will be solved? I also tried reaching @SpotifyCares on Twitter but they insist to ask it here, but I think it's an internal error of their APIs.

Thanks in advance.